# Assigning intermediate value to a variable makes the computation result complex

Tags: python, operators

Python gives me a different result if I assign one of the intermediate steps to a variable, like this:

```
>>> -0.207 ** 0.66 - 1
-1.3536229379434348
>>> a = -0.207
>>> a ** 0.66 - 1
(-1.1703591496008927+0.30988214273656856j)
```

For this simple calculation, if I assign `-0.207` to a temporary variable `a`, then the result of `a ** 0.66 - 1` evaluates to a complex number.

Why does this happen, and how do I stop Python from doing that?

Comment: This sorta blew my mind for a second.  Order of precedence baby.

Comment: yeah.... didn't know ** precedes even unary -.

Answer (score 5):

The *correct* answer to your statement (according to python) is a negative number. `-0.207**0.66-1` evaluates to about `-1.35`.
The reason this is happening is that you're miscalculating in the one-liner:
`-0.207 ** 0.66 - 1` actually evaluates to `-(0.207 ** 0.66) - 1` and not to `(-0.207) ** 0.66 - 1` like you'd expect.

When you separate the lines, you're changing the calculation to the second statement.

To stop this from happening, use explicit parentheses where there *might* be any ambiguity.

Comment: Wow. I was today years old when I learned that `**` binds more tightly than unary `-`.

Comment: Yep, I was surprised too. I guess if you explicitly write it out as `-1 * ` it makes more sense.